# ValueError: max_features must be in (0, n_features] in Random Forest

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

No code appears or error: ValueError: max_features must be in (0, n_features].
I have already tried the Stack solutions and I did not get a solution. Could anyone help?

```
def predict_RF(x_test_sel, k_vetor, y_train):
    model = RandomForestRegressor()
    model.fit(k_vetor, y_train)
    y_predict = model.predict(x_test_sel)

    kf = KFold(n_splits=3)

    n_estimators = [25, 50, 75, 100] 
    max_features = [0.2, 0,7, 0.5, 1.0]
    min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 5, 10] 

    hyperF = dict (n_estimators = n_estimators, max_features=max_features, min_samples_leaf = min_samples_leaf) 

    gridF = GridSearchCV(model, hyperF, cv = kf, verbose = 1, n_jobs = -1)

    grid_fit = gridF.fit(k_vetor, y_train) #Fit the gridsearch object with X_train, (k_vetor, y_train) -> dar nome x_train para k_vetor 
    
    print(grid_fit.best_params_)
    
    return (y_predict)
```

Comment: It is connected with some ML library(I am not Datascientist), so I can not give you specific answer. But if other solutions works, or someone(maybe someone from StackOverflow) says you that it works. Then you need to check versions of libraries you use.

Comment: Please give us some sample data, add your imports and include the full stacktrace of your error message .

Answer (score 1):

Please replace 0,7 with 0.7

```
max_features = [0.2, 0,7, 0.5, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem using max_features as float. I suggest max_features list should contain only integers. For instance:
max_features = [2, 5, 7, 10]